# iPhone App crashes even if ARC... help me finding the issue please

Tags: iphone, ios, automatic-ref-counting

i'm developing a hangman game for iPhone and iPad but sometimes it crashes.
here's the crash log of Xcode:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace: 
0   CoreFoundation              0x353e788f `__exceptionPreprocess`+ 163 
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3778e259 objc_exception_throw + 33 
2   CoreFoundation                  0x353e7789 +[NSException raise:format:] + 1 
3   CoreFoundation                  0x353e77ab +[NSException raise:format:] + 35
4   CoreFoundation                  0x35354fed`-[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:]`+ 89
5   Poke Hangman                    0x000e41f5 -[ViewController setStringWithDatabase::](ViewController.m:194)
6   Poke Hangman                    0x000e388b -[ViewController preparaStringhe:] (ViewController.m:39)
7   Poke Hangman                    0x000e4685 -[ViewController cambia] (ViewController.m:248)
8   Poke Hangman                    0x000e3bc5 -[ViewController checkChar:] (ViewController.m:81)
9   Poke Hangman                    0x000e6155 -[ViewController ButtonG:] (ViewController.m:579)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x353413fd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 53
11  UIKit                           0x32e36e07 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 63
12  UIKit                           0x32e36dc3 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 31
13  UIKit                           0x32e36da1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 45
14  UIKit                           0x32e36b11 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 493
15  UIKit                           0x32e37449 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 477
16  UIKit                           0x32e3592b -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 319
17  UIKit                           0x32e35319 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 381
18  UIKit                           0x32e1b695 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 357
19  UIKit                           0x32e1af3b _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5827
20  GraphicsServices                0x36fda22b PurpleEventCallback + 883
21  CoreFoundation                  0x353bb523 <br>`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__`+ 39
22  CoreFoundation                  0x353bb4c5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 141
23  CoreFoundation                  0x353ba313 __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
24  CoreFoundation                  0x3533d4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
25  CoreFoundation                  0x3533d36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
26  GraphicsServices                0x36fd9439 GSEventRunModal + 137
27  UIKit                           0x32e49cd5 UIApplicationMain + 1081
28  Poke Hangman                    0x000e3263 main (main.m:16)
29  Poke Hangman                    0x000e3208 start + 40


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35c9d32c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x327e9208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x327e2298 abort + 88
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3579ff64 abort_message + 40
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3579d346 _ZL17default_terminatev + 18
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3778e350 _objc_terminate + 140
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3579d3be _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 70
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3579d44a std::terminate() + 14
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3579e81e __cxa_rethrow + 82
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3778e2a2 objc_exception_rethrow + 6
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3533d506 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3533d366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
12  GraphicsServices                0x36fd9432 GSEventRunModal + 130
13  UIKit                           0x32e49cce UIApplicationMain + 1074
14  Poke Hangman                    0x000e325c main (main.m:16)
15  Poke Hangman                    0x000e3200 start + 32

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35c8d3a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x34277f04 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x34277c22 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35c8d004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35c8d1fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x353bb3ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x353ba124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3533d49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3533d366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x3123cc9c _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x327aa72e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x327aa5e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3e9f4d98      r6: 0x00000002      r7: 0x2fee09f0
    r8: 0x002ad500    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x3ee51bc0     r11: 0x00000001
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fee09e4      lr: 0x327e920f      pc: 0x35c9d32c
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

solved this issue but having a new one:

here's the crash log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x39ee717b`__exceptionPreprocess +`163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34ea095b objc_exception_throw + 31
2   CoreFoundation                  0x39ee709d -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 1
3   CoreFoundation                  0x39e4bd5b -[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:] + 87
4   Poke Hangman                    0x00077493 0x74000 + 13459
5   Poke Hangman                    0x0007644b 0x74000 + 9291
6   Poke Hangman                    0x00077a35 0x74000 + 14901
7   Poke Hangman                    0x00076839 0x74000 + 10297
8   Poke Hangman                    0x0007aa7b 0x74000 + 27259
9   UIKit                           0x32e4dd09 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 73
10  UIKit                           0x32e4dcbb -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 31
11  UIKit                           0x32e4dc95 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 45
12  UIKit                           0x32e4d9eb -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 503
13  UIKit                           0x32e4e369 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 489
14  UIKit                           0x32e4c791 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 525
15  UIKit                           0x32e3a72d -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 381
16  UIKit                           0x32e3a009 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6057
17  GraphicsServices                0x33f04603 _PurpleEventCallback + 591
18  GraphicsServices                0x33f04233 PurpleEventCallback + 35
19  CoreFoundation                  0x39eb7873 `__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__`+ 35
20  CoreFoundation                  0x39eb7817 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 139
21  CoreFoundation                  0x39eb6611 __CFRunLoopRun + 1385
22  CoreFoundation                  0x39e33be5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
23  CoreFoundation                  0x39e33a71 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
24  GraphicsServices                0x33f0334b GSEventRunModal + 75
25  UIKit                           0x32e607f5 UIApplicationMain + 1121
26  Poke Hangman                    0x00075f65 0x74000 + 8037
27  Poke Hangman                    0x00075f00 0x74000 + 7936
```

please help me finding the issue..

here's the section where i think it crashes:
isPresent tells if the user char is present in the word or not
if the user char exists in the correct word, in the critted one it get swapped at the position i. if there isn't the char the score get lower by 20.
sorry for my bad english and hope u will help me ;)

bool isPresent = NO;

```
for (int i = 0; i < correctWord.length; i++)

    if (userCharFromButton == [correctWord characterAtIndex:i])
    {
        criptedWord = [criptedWord stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1.0) withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", userCharFromButton]];
        isPresent = YES;
    }    

word.text = criptedWord;

if (isPresent == NO)
    currentlyScore -= 20;


//check if the word is complete
bool complete = YES;

for (int i = 1; i < criptedWord.length; i++)
    if ([criptedWord characterAtIndex:i] == '-')
        complete = NO;
```

Comment: 1. Despite your question title ("iPhone App crashes even if ARC..."), using ARC doesn't mean that you can write code in any way you like. You can still cause crashes. 2. Go and read Apple's developer notes for debugging. Learn to use the tools they provide you

Comment: Try putting debugger in the methods where it is crashing.

Answer (score 2):

The crash log shows a backtrace which has been symbolised. From there, you can see on the 5th item of your Last Exception Backtrace

```
5   Poke Hangman                    0x000e41f5 -[ViewController setStringWithDatabase::](ViewController.m:194)
```

It is in your setStringWithDatabase:: in the ViewController class on line 194 which is causing the exception.

On the line above, you can see

```
4   CoreFoundation                  0x35354fed`-[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:]`+ 89
```

So your setStringWithDatabase:: must be calling a CoreFoundation characterAtIndex: method which you directly call yourself or something you call invokes it around line 194 in your ViewController class. Common cause would be that your string is nil/empty or you are trying to get a character beyond the range.

The problem doesn't seem to be related to using ARC.

*[below is the solution to the second bit]*

As mentioned in my answer, your second problem also seems to be similar to the first. You need to make sure your string criptedWord is not nil and there isn't something else related to that variable which is crashing it. In order to diagnose further, you need to symbolise your crash logs first.

Comment: ok mates
i've found the exception:

before: if ([parola characterAtIndex:i] == "'") 
now:         if ([parola characterAtIndex:i] == '`')

Comment: Update your question to include some of this code, so that we can help you find the actual reason it is crashing